# Why is my neural network stuck at high loss value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, shortest-path

I have tasked myself to creating a program which (by using a neural network) find the shortest path of a directional and weighted graph.

The setting up of the this task works perfectly fine, and I get directed graphs which look like this,
[Directed graph with weights, drawn with networkx. Weights arn't shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJr2r.png) Where the start node is 0 and the end node (to find the shortest path) is fixed as the last node.

The only feature for the graphs is the weights and I create with this code, which is then imported into the main program.

```
import sonnet as snt
import graph_nets as gn

class INModel(snt.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        A graph neural network. Sets up network function.
        """
        # Create the graph network.
        super(INModel, self).__init__()
       
        size = 128
        
        self.gn_module = gn.modules.GraphNetwork(
           edge_model_fn=lambda: snt.nets.MLP([size, size, 2]),
           node_model_fn=lambda: snt.nets.MLP([size, size, 0]),
           global_model_fn=lambda: snt.nets.MLP([size, size,0])        
           )          
       
    def __call__(self, data):
        """
        Takes data and parses it through the graph network
        
        data: dictionary, [formatted_graphs, node_system, true_path]
        """
        
        print(data['dgraphs'])
        gnn = self.gn_module(data['dgraphs'])
        
        
        return gnn
```

Additionally, here is an example of my input graphtuple, with 2 graphs and a single edge for each graph (2 node systems).

```
GraphsTuple(nodes=<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 0), dtype=float32, numpy=array([], shape=(4, 0), dtype=float32)>, edges=<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[2.5975916],
       [6.0981345]], dtype=float32)>, receivers=<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 3])>, senders=<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 2])>, globals=<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 0), dtype=float32, numpy=array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=float32)>, n_node=<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2, 2])>, n_edge=<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 1])>)
[[0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]]
```

I have two classes shown in the labels, which are set up so if an edge corresponds to the true path it is labelled as `[0.,1.]` or `[1.,0.]` for edges not on the true path.

Here is my main code. The rest handles formatting and node system generation,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import graph_nets as gn
import sonnet as snt
import tensorflow as tf
import tqdm

from formatter import formatter
import nodal 
from graphs import INModel

class training:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        
        self.stat = pd.DataFrame(columns=['train_loss','test_loss'])
        self.opt = snt.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
        
    def step(self, gr_train, gr_test=None):
        test_loss=0
        if gr_test is not None:
            pred = self.model(gr_test)
            logits = pred.edges
            labels = gr_train['labels']
            #loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels)
            loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true = labels, y_pred=logits, from_logits=True)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
            
            test_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
            
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            pred = self.model(gr_train)     
            logits=pred.edges
            labels = gr_train['labels']
            
            print(labels)
            
            #loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels)
            loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true = labels, y_pred=logits, from_logits=True)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
            
            logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
            print(logits)
            
        
        params = self.model.trainable_variables
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, params)
        self.opt.apply(grads, params)
        
        self.stat=pd.concat([self.stat,pd.DataFrame({'train_loss':float(loss), 'test_loss':float(test_loss)}, index=[len(self.stat)])])
        print(self.stat)
        
        return loss
    
    
##################MAIN#####################

model = INModel()
t = training(model)
epochs = 10

gr_train = formatter(2, truth_value = True)
#gr_test = formatter(2, truth_value = True)

fig_s,ax_s=plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(24,8))
fig_t,ax_t=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))

for epoch in tqdm.trange(epochs):
    loss=float(t.step(gr_train))#, gr_test))
    
# Plot the status of the training
ax_t.clear()
ax_t.plot(t.stat.train_loss.tolist(),label='Training')
ax_t.set_yscale('log')
ax_t.set_ylabel('loss')
ax_t.set_xlabel('epoch')
ax_t.legend()
```

No matter what I seem to try, the training loss doesn't seem to dip below .5-.6. and the neural network doesn't seem to recognize any pattern. From what I've read around it appears that I may be stuck in a local minimum, however I have no idea how to get out of it if so.

I've tried changing the optimizer, the loss function, number of epochs, size of neural network, learning rate, changing from non-directional to directional, number of nodes, and number of inputted graphs, and a number of other modifications. However, none of them have given me a learning loss rate lower than ~.5.

The only time this has actually worked as intended is when I used a single edge (2 node system) where the labels are fixed (as the shortest path is of course along the only egde.)

I am hoping to get a much lower loss rate and for relatively high accuracy in testing phase.

Comment: I am not familiar with graphs, but some suggestions for troubleshooting a neural net that's not learning: [1] Make it bigger than you need, and give it fewer training samples. It should basically learn to memorise the inputs. If training loss stays high, I think something may be fundamentally wrong with it. [2] Use a small batch size - this would help with local minima as the updates become noisier. [3] Add batch norm layers, and train for longer. Taken together, I think you should end up with a net that learns your inputs. That will confirm the architecture is working & capable of learning.